# Sharing variables in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code in a WordPress theme that I am developing that checks to see if a plugin is active;

```
if ( is_plugin_active( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php' ) ) {

    $WooCommerceState = True;

}
```

The aim was that once this was set at the top of the file I could use it in the rest of the file to display certain information based on whether $WooCommerceState was True or False so I have;

```
if ( is_plugin_active( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php' ) ) {

    $WooCommerceState = True;

}

<?php if ( $WooCommerceState == True ) { ?>

..do something

<?php } ?>


<?php if ( $WooCommerceState == True ) { ?>

..do something

<?php } ?>
```

This is all within the same file, but when I view the page I get a

> Notice: Undefined variable...

message for the two tests. How can I resolve this?

Comment: which version of PHP are you using ?

Comment: When the plugin is not activated the `$WooCommerceState` is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

try this,  it's undefined when plugin not active. Should be always initialized before using

```
$WooCommerceState = is_plugin_active( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php' );
```

and remove that first if

-edited after rjdown comment. Thanks-

Comment: No need for the global

Comment: more than "scoping" it's undefined when plugin not active. Should be always initialized  before using

Comment: @rjdown you're right, I thought was scoping and needed across files